# Delphi LoggerPro -> LoggerPro.FMXMemoAppender

Tags: delphi, logging

The [GitHub repo of LoggerPro](https://github.com/danieleteti/loggerpro) does not contain a file `LoggerPro.FMXMemoAppender.pas`, but I assume this file is needed to use LoggerPro with FMX frameworks apps.

How to change VCL file to FMX file?

Comment: Make a copy of `LoggerPro.VCLMemoAppender.pas`, rename it to `LoggerPro.FMXMemoAppender.pas`, and *rewrite its code* to work with an FMX `TMemo` instead of a VCL `TMemo`. What's the problem with that? Or better, since LoggerPro claims to support FMX, why not just ask the author why an Appender  for FMX `TMemo` wasn't provided in the first place?

Comment: That already exists as [issue/enhancement ticket](https://github.com/danieleteti/loggerpro/issues/43) since 2020. Next time please check the vendor's support first.

Comment: If that appender would have been written for `TStrings` instead of `TMemo` or `TListBox` it would automatically work for the FMX TMemo and many controls more ;)